# How to change a DataGrid row colour when a certain value is encountered?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have the following DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="dgPanelLogs">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" SortMemberPath="ID"
            x:Name="columnID" 
            Binding="{Binding Path=ID}"
            IsReadOnly="True"
            Width="50*"
            SortDirection="Descending" >
        </DataGridTextColumn>

        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Time" SortMemberPath="Time" 
            x:Name="columnTime" 
            Binding="{Binding Path= Time, StringFormat='{}{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss}'}"
            IsReadOnly="True"
            Width="140*"
            SortDirection="Descending">
        </DataGridTextColumn>

        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Event" SortMemberPath="Event"
            x:Name="columnMessage" 
            Binding="{Binding Path=Message}"
            IsReadOnly="True"
            Width="350*"
            SortDirection="Descending" >
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

My new requirement is to change rows to red when a certain value is encountered. Specifically, I have to retrieve a new boolean value with each row's data, and if it's true I need to set that row's text to red.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Just for clarification, you want to set the whole row to e.g. Red.

Comment: Yes, specifically the *text* of the row, so the foreground of each cell really.

Comment: It certainly isn't the same way you would in WinForms i.e. loop through the rows colouring the background of the cells. I wrote code to do this and it is awful - it works but it is nasty. I will share if you think you could use the code, but the correct way will be to use data binding/`Triggers`/`Commands` etc.

Comment: See my question on this exact thing as well... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657348/looping-through-wpf-datagrid-using-foreach

Comment: You should investigate the use of DataTriggers and Styles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use a style.

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Alarm}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

I cant test it now. I think you have to set a RelativeSource on the Binding.

Comment: I've modified this answer. Your code was *almost* correct, so I fixed a typo and nested the `<Style` code in the context that worked.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following posts will help you.

> [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6260571/873979) : StackOverflow
>   problem and answer
>
> [link2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683.aspx) : Styling
>   and Templating